# How can I verify that requests.get() used the proxy and not my ip in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, get, ip, python-requests

I send out a GET request:
    requests.get(url, proxies={'https':'x.x.x.x:xxxx'})

How can I verify that the request went out through the proxy and not from my ip?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's going to show what your looking for but you might be able to enable the logging and see the proxy

```
logging.basicConfig() # you need to initialize logging, otherwise you will not see anything from requests
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

reference: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/
At the bottom of the pa above the proxy usage

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not seeing what I wanted to see in the log messages, however. I'm interested in proving that the server got the request from a proxy and not from me.